# Is it possible to use excel cell value - as a reference in T-SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have table in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio):

[image]

from which I need to delete data, based on the `SurveyCode` value.

Text part of the `SurveyCode` value `CSS-2020-08-` is stored in an Excel sheet, in `B4` cell, file name `Survey.xlsx`:

[image]

And, for deleting / adding new data into my `Survey` table, I use the following code:

```sql
DELETE FROM [WH].[Fact].[Survey]
WHERE [WH].[Fact].[Survey].[SurveyCode] NOT LIKE '%2020-08%'

INSERT INTO
    [WH].Fact.[Survey]  (
          [SurveyCode]
         ,[SurveyDate]
         ,[Gender]
         ,[Age]
         ,[Questions]
         ,[Rating]
         ,[Score]
                       )
SELECT 
        staged.[SurveyCode]
       ,staged.[SurveyDate]
       ,staged.[Gender]
       ,staged.[Age]
       ,staged.[Question]
       ,staged.[Rating]
       ,staged.[Score]

FROM 
      [WH-SSIS].[WHCSS].[Staged_Survey] staged;
```

Is it possible - instead of using the SQL statement:

```sql
WHERE [WH].[Fact].[Survey].[SurveyCode] NOT LIKE '%2020-08%'
```

to reference `CSS-2020-08-` directly from the Excel spreadsheet - right inside the SQL statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code to read xlsx sheet into a table in a SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150739/code-to-read-xlsx-sheet-into-a-table-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: A set consisting of one cell is a valid set.

Comment: So [put that range in the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56284138/11683)?

Comment: @GSerg   Openrowset works with FROM clause (with select from)
But in my case I need something for WHERE clause...    Openrowset won't work with WHERE   I think

Comment: Does the account under which SQL Server runs have permissions to access that file?

Comment: Does the account under which SQL Server runs have permissions to access that file?  yes

Comment: @GSerg Actually, I removed my updates!  Openrowset () will insert all data from excel to SQL table.  That's not what I need. I am looking for a solution - to insert data from one SQL db to another, WHERE SurveyCode from excel has a certain value

Comment: @Hell-1931 That isn't how tsql works. You need to reference a specific column in a specific row - regardless of where that "table" is located. You can't reference "B4" directly - you must get the value based on the primary or unique values that identify that row in your "table". This is beginning to sound like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Perhaps the better approach is to build and execute your query from excel using some vba to directly access a particular cell in a particular sheet (yes - you skipped the "sheet" part - an excel file can contain multiple sheets). Perhaps change your ETL process to delete the existing rows first?

Comment: Openrowset does not insert anything. Openrowset lets you read Excel cells. You specify which cells you want to read.

Comment: @GSerg  Sorry, my bad, I was kind of desperate yesterday   Yes, it READS from excel; not inserts ....    Below answer is explaining how to fight my issues

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
declare @parameter nvarchar(50)
SELECT parameter =f2
FROM OPENROWSET(
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;Database=T:\temp\Survey.xlsx',
'select f2 from [sheet1$] where f1='''SurveyCode'''')
```

then you can use parameter in

```
WHERE [WH].[Fact].[Survey].[SurveyCode] NOT LIKE '%'+@parameter+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading the xlsx file, first of all you will need to have the right provider installed, you can check that by:

```
USE [master];
EXEC sys.sp_enum_oledb_providers;
```

You should see Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.XX.0, where XX can be typically either 12 or 16. If you don't see it, then you will need to install the provider. Find it from MS [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

Then, you will need to have 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' enabled. You can check it by running:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries';
```

If above command does not work and you are admin, then you will need to run below commands:

```
USE [master];
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

It is also good to check some more settings:

```
USE master;
EXEC dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop;
```

See allow_in_process and dynamic_parameters values for Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 on this example. If they are 0, you will need to enable them as well:

```
USE master;
EXEC dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1;
EXEC dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1;
```

After all above checks, be sure the user which is running SSMS has read permissions for the xlsx file you want to read.

Finally, you should be able to run a query like below with no issues:

```
DECLARE @parameter NVARCHAR(50);
SELECT @parameter = F2
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
        'Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;Database=D:\temp\Survey.xlsx',
        'select * from [sheet1$]') AS xlsx
    WHERE xlsx.F1 = 'SurveyCode';
```

And you can use the @parameter value as part of your query:

```
...NOT LIKE '%'+@parameter+'%'
```

Comment: One other question - what is F2  and F1 in your code?